# Format negative currency of USD to display a minus sign in a JOptionPane dialog box

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting, joptionpane, currency-formatting

How do I get `NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();` to print negative USD currency with a minus sign?

I'm using a JOptionPane dialog box to display the currency output for stock transactions.

```
NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total profit made: " 
+ defaultFormat.format(totalProfit_RH));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that differs from the default format, you're gonna have to make your own, but don't worry, it's not hard.

```
DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;$-#,##0.00");
```

This will create your own format, feel free to edit it as much as you want. If you do want to change it, google for "mask formatting java" and craft your own mask.

All in all, your code should look like this

```
DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;$-#,##0.00");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total profit made: " + myFormat.format(totalProfit_RH));
```